# React web is receiving 403 error while calling backend

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-config

I have deployed my **Springboot** backend and **React** front end on same **ec2** instance.

I am able to open my website. And also I am able to hit the backend using postman. But when I am calling the backend api from React app using axios, it is giving 403 error.

I have configured the **nginx** also. Tried everything, your help would be much appreciated

**Cors in Springboot application:**

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://x.x.x.x")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

**Nginx config:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name x.x.x.x;
    location / {
        root /home/ec2-user/build;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location api/ {
        proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:8080;  # Adjust port and URL as needed
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the complete 403 error response? You can use your browser's network debugging feature to get this info.